# Identity framework ASP.NET Core allow @company.com register only

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

How can I only allow `@companyname.com` email addresses in my ASP.NET Core web application with identity framework?

In my application I have different roles & two email addresses the `company.com` & `company.cs`.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? What code can you provide? How about a simple check on your signup page?

Comment: do you still need help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use scaffold Identity, you could add [custom validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-validation) attribute and apply it on your Register EmailAddress property.

In order to create a custom validation attribute you need to create a class that inherits from `ValidationAttribute` base class and override its `IsValid()` method.

```
public class IdentityEmailAttribute:ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string email = value.ToString();

        if (email.EndsWith("@companyname.com") == false)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid Email Address which does not end with @companyname.com");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Once created you can apply the `[IdentityEmail]` attribute on top of the Email property of your InputModel in Register.cshtml.cs:

```
public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [IdentityEmail]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        //other properties
    }
```